# Mastermind game, python, Choosing colour

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a mastermind game, but I can't figure out how to take the user's input from the text box for that to be used to fill in one of the squares with the colour.

This is the code:

```
import pygame

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0 , 0, 255)

WIDTH = 20
HEIGHT = 20
WIDTH1 = 30
HEIGHT1 = 30

MARGIN = 5
MARGIN1 = 10

array_width = 4
array_height = 8

grid = []
for row in range(10):
    grid.append([])
    for column in range(10):
        grid[row].append(0)

colors = [(0, 0, 0) for i in range(array_width * array_height)]
blocks = [False for i in range(array_width * array_height)]

pygame.init()

# Set the HEIGHT and WIDTH of the screen
WINDOW_SIZE = [300, 300]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)

# Set title of screen
pygame.display.set_caption("MASTERMIND GAME")
sair = True
done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
grid[row][column] = 1

#TEXT BOX VARIABLES AND DATA
base_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
user_text = ""
input_rect = pygame.Rect (10,250,100,50)
color_active = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')
color_passive = pygame.Color('gray15')
color=color_passive
active = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print (blocks)
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            column = pos[0] // (WIDTH + MARGIN)
            row = pos[1] // (HEIGHT + MARGIN)
            print(row)
            print(column)
            # TEXT BOX CREATION AND USAGE
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if input_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                active = True
            else:
                active = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if active == True:
                if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    user_text = user_text[0:-1]
                else:
                    user_text += event.unicode
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                user_text = user_text
                print(user_text)

            # check if column and row are valid grid indices
            if 0 <= column < array_height and 0 <= row < array_width:

                blocks[row * array_height + column] = not blocks[row * array_height + column]
                # toggle
                for row in range(array_width):
                    for column in range(array_height):

                        # CHECK IF BLOCK SHOULD BE CHANGED
                        if blocks[column * array_width + row]:
                            if user_text == 'blue':
                                colors[column * array_height + row] = (0, 0, 255)

            print("Click ", pos, "Grid coordinates: ", row, column)

    if active:
        color = color_active
    else:
        color=color_passive
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,input_rect,2)
    text_surface= base_font.render(user_text,True,(255,255,255))
    screen.blit(text_surface, (input_rect.x +5, input_rect.y + 5))

    for row in range(8):
        for column in range(4):
            color = WHITE
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,
                             color,
                             [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN,
                              (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN,
                              WIDTH,
                              HEIGHT])

    clock.tick(60)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

This is what the GUI looks like

[image: GUI]

I do have a method using something like this

```
 for row in range(10):
    for column in range(10):
        color = WHITE
        if grid[row][column] == 1:
            color = GREEN
        if grid[row][column] == 2:
            color = RED
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,
                         color,
                         [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN,
                          (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN,
                          WIDTH,
                          HEIGHT])
```

But when clicking on the text box it says  `index out of range`, so I think I should probably use a different method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable for the color and create a grid with the current color:

```py
current_color = "white"
grid = [[current_color for column in range(4)] for row in range(8)]
```

When you click a cell, assign the current color to the cell:

```py
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # [...]

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print (blocks)
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            column = pos[0] // (WIDTH + MARGIN)
            row = pos[1] // (HEIGHT + MARGIN)
            
            if 0 <= row < array_height and 0 <= column < array_width:
                try:
                    grid[row][column] = current_color
                except:
                    print("invalid color")
```

Change the current color when <kbd>RETURN</kbd> is pressed:

```py
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # [...]

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                user_text = user_text
                print(user_text)
                if user_text != "":
                    current_color = user_text
                user_text = ""
```

Use the colors from the grid for drawing:

```py
while not done:
    # [...]

    for row, gridrow in enumerate(grid):
        for column, color in enumerate(gridrow):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,
                             color,
                             [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN,
                              (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN,
                              WIDTH,
                              HEIGHT])
```

---

Complete example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0 , 0, 255)

WIDTH = 20
HEIGHT = 20
WIDTH1 = 30
HEIGHT1 = 30

MARGIN = 5
MARGIN1 = 10

array_width = 4
array_height = 8

grid = []
for row in range(10):
    grid.append([])
    for column in range(10):
        grid[row].append(0)

colors = [(0, 0, 0) for i in range(array_width * array_height)]
blocks = [False for i in range(array_width * array_height)]

pygame.init()

# Set the HEIGHT and WIDTH of the screen
WINDOW_SIZE = [300, 300]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)

# Set title of screen
pygame.display.set_caption("MASTERMIND GAME")
sair = True
done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
grid[row][column] = 1

#TEXT BOX VARIABLES AND DATA
base_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
user_text = ""
input_rect = pygame.Rect (10,250,100,50)
color_active = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')
color_passive = pygame.Color('gray15')
color=color_passive
active = False

current_color = "white"
grid = [[current_color for column in range(4)] for row in range(8)]

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print (blocks)
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            column = pos[0] // (WIDTH + MARGIN)
            row = pos[1] // (HEIGHT + MARGIN)
            print(row)
            print(column)
            # TEXT BOX CREATION AND USAGE

            # check if column and row are valid grid indices
            if 0 <= row < array_height and 0 <= column < array_width:
                try:
                    grid[row][column] = current_color
                except:
                    print("invalid color")

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if input_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                active = True
            else:
                active = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if active == True:
                if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    user_text = user_text[0:-1]
                else:
                    user_text += event.unicode
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                user_text = user_text
                print(user_text)
                if user_text != "":
                    current_color = user_text
                user_text = ""

            print("Click ", pos, "Grid coordinates: ", row, column)

    if active:
        color = color_active
    else:
        color=color_passive

    screen.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,input_rect,2)
    text_surface= base_font.render(user_text,True,(255,255,255))
    screen.blit(text_surface, (input_rect.x +5, input_rect.y + 5))

    for row, gridrow in enumerate(grid):
        for column, color in enumerate(gridrow):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,
                             color,
                             [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN,
                              (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN,
                              WIDTH,
                              HEIGHT])

    clock.tick(60)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Its so obvious once you see how it works, thanks a lot